# When ending a sentence with an adverb, do I need to use copula?

Tags: adverbs

pretty basic question, but I was curious if an adverb needs copula (like a noun, or na-adjective) or not (like an i-adjective).

For example:

1. たいへんだそう or たいへんそう
2. ぴったり（+だ？）
3. 私はズバズバ（+だ？）<- can i even use a sentence like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In casual/colloquial speech, you can often (but not always) drop the copula だ・です after adverbs such as くたくた、ふらふら、こりごり、がらがら (同じ音を繰り返すもの), がっかり、しっとり、さっぱり (「〇っ〇り」「〇ん〇り」の形のもの) -- those that generally can function as a する-verb or an onomatopoeia.

e.g.

> このぬいぐるみはふわふわだ。 → このぬいぐるみ、ふわふわ。
>   おなかがぺこぺこです。 → おなかぺこぺこ。
>   このスカートはぴったりだ。 → このスカート、ぴったり。
>   もううんざりです。 → もううんざり。

---

> たいへんだ**そう** or たいへん**そう**

Actually, no adverb is used in these examples. The そう's used here are an auxiliary (dictionary form: そうだ), not an adverb. たいへん's used here are both a na-adjective, not an adverb.

But if you're asking whether they can be used at the end of a sentence with no copula attached...

> (様態) たいへんそうです。 → たいへんそう。

It's common to use it that way in casual/colloquial speech.

Regarding:

> (伝聞) たいへんだそうです。 → たいへんだそう。

It's also okay, though you might see 「～だそう。」 more in the written form (eg ブログやエッセイなど). (In casual/colloquial speech, we often say 「たいへんらしい。」「たいへんみたい。」 or 「たいへんなんだって。」 etc.)